# I have one timer and I am having a few problems with this timer

Tags: android, kotlin, timer, fragment

```
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment)
    binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    object : CountDownTimer(100000,100){
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
           batteryText.text = "Akü Şarj Durumu: %${millisUntilFinished/1000}"
       }

        override fun onFinish() {
           batteryText.text = "Akü Şarj Durumu: %0"
     }

  }.start()
}
```

I have a simple timer and I have the following problems with this timer;

1-) No matter what I do, the millisInFuture and countDownInterval values in the Timer cannot count from 100 one by one, every 10 seconds.

2-) If I try to switch to another page before the timer runs out, the application crashes. When the timer ends, there is no problem when you switch to another page. Why?

3-) I want the timer to continue counting even though I switch to another page. When I come back to the page, I don't want it to start from 100 again. I want the user to see that number when the user comes to the page with the timer, if the application has decreased during the time it is used.

Comment: You need to cancel the timer when you move from one screen to another. Before doing that remember where the timer is at and start the timer again when you come back from next screen. `int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60 `

Answer (score 0):

If you want the timer to tick every 10 seconds then interval i.e. the second parameter should be 10000 milli (10 seconds) and since you want to get 100 such ticks it should be 100 * 10 seconds = 1000 seconds or 1000000 milli in future i.e. the first parameter.

Your application crashes because it receives a tick call after the user has moved away from screen and you are trying to change something in the view.

If you want the timer to run even when the user has moved away from the activity then you should host the timer in a **foreground service** or a **bound service** instead.